# Matching a simple string using Regex?

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string like this:

```
*select 65* description
```

How could I extract the bit after the asterisk and the number using **regex** in Python? I need something that would yield `select` and `65` from the above string.

All of them follow this convention:

```
*[lowercase specifier] [integer]* description
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
^\*([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]+)\*
```

In Python, you can match regular expressions with [the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Thus:

```
import re

my_string = """*select 65* description"""
match = re.match(r"^\*([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]+)\*", my_string)
specifier = match.group(1)
integer = int(match.group(2))
```

Comment: Note that the specified regular expression will match one or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs) between the "lowercase specifier" and the "integer" sections.  If the match should be strict, replace the `\s+` part and put a real space character.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
```

and then either

```
m = re.match(r"^\*([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]+)\*\s+(.*)", "*select 65* description")
print m.groups()
```

or

```
r = re.compile(r"^\*([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]+)\*\s+(.*)")
m = r.match("*select 65* description")
print m.groups()
```

depending on the number of matches you want to make. The former is better suited for one or few matches, the latter better for many, because the regex is compiled in a form which is better suited for multiple executions.

Comment: Ouch, sorry, too much. As icktoofay wrote, the regex to use would be `r"^\*([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]+)\*"`, as you are not interested in the description.

Answer (score 1):

Python's regex library is powerful, but I'm personally fond of using split() for lighter-weight problems:

```
>>> s = "*select 65* description"
>>> s.split('*')
['', 'select 65', ' description']
>>> s.split('*')[1].split()
['select', '65']
```

Comment: Maybe, but this doesn't validate that the "lowercase specifier" is actually lower case or that the "integer" part is actually an integer, so you'll have to perform extra error checking.

Comment: +1 for not using regex. Don't use regex if you have other simple solutions.